# Hive - how to get the quantile on values per group

Tags: hadoop, hive

How can I calculate the quantile (ntile, or percentile) for a value, for each group of rows of the same item?

I would like to know for item '101', considering only the rows where 'p' is 1, which is the value needed to be in the top 25% for example.

```
create table t1
(item INT,
p INT,
value FLOAT
);

insert into t1 values ('101', '1', '.5');
insert into t1 values ('101', '2', '.4');
insert into t1 values ('101', '1', '.6');
insert into t1 values ('101', '2', '.2');
insert into t1 values ('101', '1', '.7');
insert into t1 values ('101', '2', '.3');
insert into t1 values ('102', '1', '1.5');
insert into t1 values ('102', '2', '1.4');
insert into t1 values ('102', '1', '1.6');
insert into t1 values ('102', '2', '1.2');
insert into t1 values ('102', '1', '1.7');
insert into t1 values ('102', '2', '1.3');
```

I have tried the following but get an error.

```
SELECT 
    item,
    p,
    value,
NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY value DESC) AS quartile
FROM t1
group by item
where p=1
```

Error message:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED ParseException line 8:0
>   missing EOF at 'where' near item

I can do it in R, with a command like:

```
d[p==1, quantile(value, .75, na.rm=TRUE), by=item]
```

but I need this in Hadoop for performance reasons.

Answer (score 16):

In Hive using Percentile function we can find the quantile values.

Below query is used to find the 25th,50th,75th percentile values for each item.

```
 select item,p,percentile_approx(value,array(0.25,0.50.0.75)) 
 from t1 where p=1 group by item,p;
```

Below query is used to find the given percentile values for each item.

```
select item,p,percentile_approx(value,0.5) 
from t1 where p=1 group by item,p;
```

Comment: How can i calculate decile using the above UDFs?

Answer (score 5):

"Where" should come before "group by"